# How can I say "Soplar (una respuesta)" in English, to make it less formal as "giving a hint"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, coloquialismos

Mi problema surge de la redacción (en inglés) de una pregunta que estoy redactando para codereview.SE. Es importante para mí decir que, en el código que utilizo, los resultados "me soplan" posibles respuestas a un problema, es decir, me dan una pista, más formalmente hablando.

**La pregunta**: En el caso más formal diría "giving a hint", por ejemplo. Pero cuando es algo más informal: ¿qué dirían ustedes? Asumamos que no es necesaria *tanta* formalidad, por ejemplo.

---

I'm concerned about writing something like:

> the output of a script is *giving me a hint* that is relevant to...

I wonder how should I write it if, *hypothetically*, I'd want the readers to sense less formality, maybe. In Spanish (Chile, at least), for instance, we use "soplar" (the same used to blow air) instead of giving *when* what you give is **not a hint** but an answer (which is indeed a hint).

**The question**: how would you write it?

Comment: 1. (subject) whisper/pass the answers to sb. 2. the results suggest/give an consistent trend/give a more comprehensible picture/hint at some interesting trends/conclusions.

Comment: Estás buscando una palabra en inglés, por lo que entiendo. Aquí podemos ayudar, por supuesto, pero lo veo más de [english.se] o [ell.se].

Comment: Forget whisper etc. in English. That does not work here. **The script output gives me a cue or provides a cue that is relevant to**...soplar is to cue, as used in the theater or acting.

Comment: "The script output suggests an answer to me" might work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that if we take the whole phrase

> the output of a script is giving me a hint that is relevant to...

the translation would have to end with a noun to be followed by *that is relevant to*. If we are allowed to rewrite the whole thing then

> the output of the script suggests to me that ...
> the output of the script suggests a solution
> the output of the script suggests a new line of enquiry